# Is it possible to use \index{\command} inside a \DeclareDocumentCommand?

Tags: indexing, xparse, xstring

So I've been writing a book of sorts where I've used `xparse` to create some commands and environments. Now, when the thing is almost done, I realised a index would be great to have! One of the environments I've created takes an argument and gives a nice little box with a argument as title. All of these boxes uses the form `foo: bar` as titles, and i want to index `bar`.

I realised `xstring` could help me and tested `\index{\StrBehind{foo: bar}{:}}` which works without a hassle (see MWE), but when i declare the command

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \cutindex {m}{\index{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}}
```

I get the error

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
---Mumbo which is better to read from MWE---
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
```

I've also tried using a temporay command to save the string, but this does not work either.

```
\newcommand{\tempor}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \cutindex {m}{
\renewcommand{\tempor}{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}
\index{\tempor}
}
```

I've come to the conclusion that `\index{\command}` does indeed work in ordinary text, but not in `\DeclareDOcumentCommand` (or `\newcommand`). Is it possible to bypass this restriction somehow?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \cutindex {m}{\index{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
This works! \index{\StrBehind{Foo: Bar}{:}}

This does not work! \cutindex{Bar: Foo}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joseph Wright's diagnosis is correct: you can't execute commands such as `\StrBehind` in an `\index` entry.

Here's a different solution using `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cutindex}{m}
 {
  \robert_cutindex:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__robert_entry_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \robert_cutindex:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__robert_entry_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { .*? \: \s* } { } \l__robert_entry_tl
  \index{ \l__robert_entry_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here's a standard entry: \index{Foo}

This works! \cutindex{Bar: Foo}

And this also! \cutindex{Bar:Foo}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note that spaces after the colon are ignored, so they can be used or not. The search regular expression finds all characters up to the first colon (followed by zero or more spaces); the replacement consists simply in throwing them away.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to take a look at your `.idx` file to see that 'works' here is not quite what you are expecting: you'll see

```
\indexentry{\StrBehind{Foo: Bar}{:}}{1}
\indexentry{\let \reserved@d =*\def \par }{1}
```

The reason is that `\index` reads it's argument verbatim. That's fine when it is not inside another command, but if you've already grabbed the argument it fails. You also see an issue if you've already *tokenized* the input, which is what you've done using

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \cutindex {m}{\index{\StrBehind{#1}{:}}}
```

as `\StrBehind` is a command, rather than a string.

There's also an issue that `\StrBehind` is not expandable, which means that even without the `\index` business you can't simply stick it into places where you want text. However, you can use an optional argument to store the result in a macro, then expand that in the right place (it's a string, so this is safe).

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \cutindex {m}{%
  \StrBehind{#1}{:}[\tempa]%
  \index{\tempa}%
}
```

(You'll notice that I've not bothered to expand `\tempa` as I know that `\index` will do this when it writes to the `.idx` file.)

Comment: It should be `\StrBehind{#1}{: }[\tempa]` or the space will be written in the index file.

Comment: @egreg I just took the info from the question: presumably it's deliberate

Comment: For me, it doesn't matter since they're just supposed to appear once and the space doesn't appear in the pdf. For people who stumble upon this, @egreg version treat `\cutindex{Foo: Bar}` and `\cutindex{Foo:Bar}` as one entry in the index, whereas this solution treat that as two different entries.

Comment: @RobinMöller The space doesn't show in the output, but it's used for sorting.